# How should I install TexLive 2017 on my Devuan Ascii / Debian Stretch?

Tags: debian, latex, devuan

Debian Stretch / Devuan Ascii comes with TexLive 2016.20170123-5 , and I want to install TeXLive 2017. What's the best way to do that without messing up my system with conflicts between the distro packages and my own installation?

I don't mind using some packages from Debian sid / Devuan ceres; but I'm not sure that's the right thing to do. Maybe I should just try removing as many TeX packages as I can and do a manual install under `/usr/local/`?

Comment: I would try listing  the dependencies and if it too many, would do a manual installing.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: There are a gazillion TeX-related packages.

Comment: I would try listing the dependencies with apt but would not let it install. Would revert the confs it too many. Depending on the situation, it might be easier having a sid VM if you need the new version that badly.

Comment: The cleanest way is probably to add the Debian/Devuan distro with TeXLive 2017 to apt, and use apt-pinning (google) to give preference to stretch/ascii. You can overwrite this preference for the TeXLive package(s) in apt-get/aptitude. I've had a system with multiple distro versions like this for a long time. However, you *will* have to pay attention to what packages will get installed by your actions, and you *may* get some packages from the newer versions.

Answer (score -3):

I just used this in devuan:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full tex4ht
```

For me it worked.